# Why doesn't vDSP_maxv find the max value in the vector?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers, vdsp, unsafemutablepointer, accelerate

`vDSP_maxv` is not assigning the max value to `output` in the code below.

I expected the last line to print `2`, but instead it prints something different each time, usually a very large or small number like `2.8026e-45`

I've read [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148569/unsafe-swift), the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450621-vdsp_maxv), and the inline documentation in the header file for `vDSP_maxv`, but I don't see why the code below isn't producing the expected result.

Making `numbers` an `UnsafePointer` instead of an `UnsafeMutablePointer` didn't work, nor did a number of other things I've tried, so maybe I'm missing something fundamental.

```
import Accelerate

do {
    // INPUT - pointer pointing at: 0.0, 1.0, 2.0
    let count = 3
    let numbers = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>
        .allocate(capacity: count)
    defer { numbers.deinitialize() }
    for i in 0..<count {
        (numbers+i).initialize(to: Float(i))
    }

    // OUTPUT
    var output = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>
        .allocate(capacity: 1)

    // FIND MAX
    vDSP_maxv(
        numbers,
        MemoryLayout<Float>.stride,
        output,
        vDSP_Length(count)
    )
    print(output.pointee) // prints various numbers, none of which are expected
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaking the usage of the stride parameter to `vDSP_maxv`.
You need to pass **the number of elements** consisting a single stride, not the number of bytes.

[vDSP_maxv(*:*:*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450621-vdsp_maxv)

> ```
> *C = -INFINITY;
> for (n = 0; n < N; ++n)
>     if (*C < A[n*I])
>         *C = A[n*I];
> ```

In the pseudo code above, `I` represents the stride parameter, and you see giving 4 (`MemoryLayout<Float>.stride`) to `I` would generate indexes exceeding the bound of `A` (your `numbers`).

Some other parts fixed to fit my preference, but the most important thing is the second parameter for `vDSP_maxv`:

```
import Accelerate

do {
    // INPUT - pointer pointing at: 0.0, 1.0, 2.0
    let numbers: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]

    // OUTPUT
    var output: Float = Float.nan

    // FIND MAX
    vDSP_maxv(
        numbers,
        1, //<- when you want to use all elements in `numbers` continuously, you need to pass `1`
        &output,
        vDSP_Length(numbers.count)
    )
    print(output) //-> 2.0
}
```